# Using Gurobi in C++17 (CLion) - "Could not find Gurobi (missing_GUROBI_LIBRARY)"

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, c++17, clion, gurobi

I am trying to use Gurobi in my CLion environment. CLion alone runs perfectly with the MSVC compiler.

```
    Clion - version 2020.3.1
    Visual Studio - 2019
    C++ 17
    Gurobi version 9.0.3
```

To install Gurobi I followed this installation guide:

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html#section:Installation

To use in CLion I added this to my CMakeLists.txt:

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039499751-How-do-I-use-CMake-to-build-Gurobi-C-C-projects-

I already have some Gurobi code where the Library is already included: #include "gurobi_c++.h"

When I run my code now, I get this error message:

```
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2020.3.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake- 
    3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
    Could NOT find GUROBI (missing: GUROBI_LIBRARY)
```

[My CMakeList.txt is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBgax.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to link the correct version of the Gurobi library. Please check the `FindGUROBI.cmake` file and modify the `NAMES` line according to your installed Gurobi version (e.g. `gurobi90`):

```
find_library(GUROBI_LIBRARY
    NAMES gurobi gurobi91
    HINTS ${GUROBI_DIR} $ENV{GUROBI_HOME}
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
```

Please also make sure to set the environment variable `GUROBI_HOME` to point to your installation directory.